# Exchange energy per electron in uniform electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, gas

All day, I have been trying to get the correct expression for the exchange energy per electron of a uniform electron gas.

All references agree on the units (Hartree units) and the following notation:
$$
\zeta = \frac{n^\uparrow - n^\downarrow}{n}, \qquad f(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{ (1 + \zeta)^{4/3} + (1-\zeta)^{4/3} -2 }{2(2^{1/3} - 1)}
$$

Reference 1 (NIST) says:

$$
\varepsilon_x(r_s,\zeta) = \varepsilon_x^P(r_s) + [\varepsilon_x^F(r_s) - \varepsilon_x^P(r_s) ] f(\zeta) 
$$
$$
\varepsilon_x^P(r_s) = 2^{-1/3}\varepsilon_x^F(r_s) = -3\left( \frac{9}{32 \pi^2} \right)^{1/3}r_s^{-1}
$$

Reference 2 (R.M.Martin - Electronic structure) says:

Method 1:
$$
\varepsilon_x(n^\uparrow,n^\downarrow) = \varepsilon_x^\uparrow + \varepsilon_x^\downarrow = \sum_\sigma -\frac{3}{4} \left( \frac{6}{\pi} n^\sigma \right)^{1/3}
$$
Method 2:
$$
\varepsilon(n,\zeta)_x =  \varepsilon_x(n,0) + [\varepsilon_x(n,1) - \varepsilon_x(n,0) ] f(\zeta) 
$$
for
$$
\varepsilon = \varepsilon^\uparrow + \varepsilon^\downarrow
$$

In all three cases, I get different values for the exchange!
For example, letting 
$$n = 3 \ \ \text{and} \ \ n^\uparrow = 2, \ \ \text{and} \ \ n^\downarrow = 1 \implies \zeta = 1/3, \implies f(\zeta) = 0.0960$$
This yields for example: For refernce 1:
$$\varepsilon_x^P(r_s) = -2.1303  \ \text{Ha} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \varepsilon_x^F(r_s) = -2.6841  \ \text{Ha} \implies \varepsilon_x(r_s,\zeta) = -2.1835  \ \text{Ha}$$
For reference 2 (Method 1)
$$\varepsilon_x^\uparrow = -1.1723  \ \text{Ha}\ \ \text{and} \ \ \varepsilon_x^\downarrow = -0.9305  \ \text{Ha} \implies \varepsilon_x(n^\uparrow, n^\downarrow) = -2.1029  \ \text{Ha}$$
Reference 2(Method 2):
$$\varepsilon_x(n,0) = -2.1303 \ \text{Ha} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \varepsilon_x(n,1) = -1.3420 \ \text{Ha}\implies \varepsilon_x(n,\zeta) = -2.0546 \ \text{Ha}$$

How do I know who to trust?